# How to make rectangle selection on QgsMapCanvas?

Tags: qgis, c++, qt

I have this code for create and open raster map:

```
if(QFile::exists(rasterFileName))
{
    QFileInfo myRasterFileInfo(rasterFileName);
    m_pRasterLayer = QSharedPointer<QgsRasterLayer>(
        new QgsRasterLayer(myRasterFileInfo.filePath(), 
        myRasterFileInfo.completeBaseName()));

    if (m_pRasterLayer->isValid())
    {
        QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(
            m_pRasterLayer.data(), true);

        QList<QgsMapCanvasLayer> layerList;
        layerList.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(m_pRasterLayer.data(), true));

        m_pMapCanvas->setLayerSet(layerList);

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

How can I make (write code for) rectangle selection by mouse on my map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolselectrectangle.cpp) of the class `QgsMapToolSelectRectangle` to get an idea of how to select by rectangle on your map.

`QgsMapToolSelectRectangle` allows you to get a rectangle from mouse events, draw it as a rubber band on the QgsMapCanvas and perform a select operation on your data.

[This code snippet](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolselectrectangle.cpp#L105) performs the selection:

```
  if ( mRubberBand )
  {
    QgsMapToolSelectUtils::setRubberBand( mCanvas, mSelectRect, mRubberBand );

    QgsGeometry* selectGeom = mRubberBand->asGeometry();
    if ( !mDragging )
    {
      bool doDifference = e->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ? true : false;
      QgsMapToolSelectUtils::setSelectFeatures( mCanvas, selectGeom, false, doDifference, true );
    }
    else
      QgsMapToolSelectUtils::setSelectFeatures( mCanvas, selectGeom, e );

    delete selectGeom;

    mRubberBand->reset( QGis::Polygon );
    delete mRubberBand;
    mRubberBand = 0;
  }
```

As you can see, it [relies on the class](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolselectutils.cpp) `QgsMapToolSelectUtils`, which does the work [from line 138 on](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolselectutils.cpp#L138) (`setSelectFeatures()` method):

`QgsFeatureIterator fit = vlayer->getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect( selectGeomTrans.boundingBox() ).setFlags( QgsFeatureRequest::ExactIntersect ).setSubsetOfAttributes( QgsAttributeList() ) );`

---

By the way, no idea of your use case, but why not doing it in Python? Are you developing a C++ core plugin?